# open webpage inside the HTML Body

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I use the following code for open webpage inside the HTML page.
[image]

but its opening in another tab instead of that html page.

I need to open google webpage inside of the HTML body instead of another tab?

Comment: takle a look at iframe

Comment: Google busts iframe

Answer (score 2):

In your HTML you might have something like

```
<body>

  <iframe id="myIframe" src=""></iframe>

</body>
```

Then in your function

```
var url = 'www.google.com';

document.getElementById('myIframe').src = url;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Look at w3school for this simple information.
http://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/tag_iframe.asp

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you trying open new page using `_self`. Try to add "_self" as next parameter in open. Read more here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Try following code

```
var Url = "https://www.google.com";
window.open(Url, "_self");
```